# how to get a 2 legged authentication on autodesk forge

Tags: authentication, autodesk-forge

i  have generated a token using a get request and when i am making an api call the call is getting failed so pls add up your suggestion's

[here is the error where i am getting an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UHWd.png) ,[here is the access token which is generated from the 2-legged authentication how do i verify the access token and make a api call to the Autodesk forge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6431.png)

Answer (score 0):

http status code 401 means that server doesn't know who you are. it may occur when you didn't put 'Authorization' in your request headers (or maybe in an incorrect form).

so make sure you have put 'Authorization' in your http request headers and try again!

(note that you have to add 'Bearer ' in front of your access token, and there's a blank after 'Bearer')

```
{
    Authorization : 'Bearer ' + <your token>
}
```